# ASP .Net project deploy package created under very long path

Tags: asp.net, tfs, msbuild

I am running the below MSBUILD command with the arguments,  this creates a package.zip file fine.

MSBUILD /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:PackageLocation=$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)\

The trouble is that the package is created with a very long path . Is there a way to reduce the path and set it so that i can control the zip file creation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply assign a package location that you want for argument `/p:PackageLocation`, such as:

```
/p:PackageFileName=some\package.zip
```

Comment: /p:PackageLocation=$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)\ is creating the zip file in the desired location, but the zip file has a log directory structure, that is the web application files are inside many directories. Let me know if i am confusing more.

Comment: Which version of TFS are you using? Do you use XAML build or new build system? If you use vNext build, it's easy to add a task "Copy Files" to copy the .zip package to the location you want. If you use XAML build, you can write and check in a script, and specify a post-build script path in your XAML build definition. You can refer to this script (tfsbuildextensions.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Script‌​s/…) which gathers some of the typical binary types from the typical locations and copies them to the folder from which TFBuild copies and drops to your staging location.